# Is it possible to index a legacy repository in nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-indexer

I'm trying to migrate a large maven1 installation to maven2. I've installed nexus 1.5, created a legacy hosted repository and a m2 virtal view of it. 
Maven 2 build scripts can access the artifacts without any problem. The only thing which is not working is the nexus-index for the legacy repository. 
Now, the legacy hosted repository doesn't have any option to be include in search, and the virtual m2 view doesn't seem to be included in the index either.

Is there any way to make an old legacy maven 1 repository searchable by nexus ?

Comment: I wonder how the Nexus Indexer behave with the legacy layout. Did you try to run it on your repo? http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Nexus+indexer#NexusIndexer-indexer

Comment: The command line indexer does not find anything.
Scanning started
Artifacts added:   0
Artifacts deleted: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *Proxying Maven 1 legacy Repositories as a Maven 2 Repo* ([NEXUS-29](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-29)):

> Note that you can't browse or search the index in nexus because it is a Maven 1 repo.

I wonder if this is because the Nexus Indexer doesn't index a legacy repository (in which case you can maybe implement or extend the indexer) or if it's "just" a limitation. Maybe open an issue in their [Jira](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS) to get a more precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing M1 repositories is not supported by the indexer. Since Maven3 is dropping support of M1 layouts, it's unlikely that we would add this. Also note that the Indexer code is being granted to the Maven project, so if someone wants to improve it with this support, you can do it there.